# Change name of :id in nested route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a nested route in rails, and I need to change the name of the :id, I don't want that :id because I haven an other field to use as parameter... I've been googling around but couldn't find a way of doing this... Any idea?

I have:

```
resources :user do
   resources :elements, :only=>[:create,:destroy]
end
```

and a rake routes generates:

```
user_elements POST   /users/:user_id/elements(.:format)          elements#create
user_elements DELETE /users/:user_id/elements/:id(.:format)       elements#destroy
```

And I need something like

```
user_elements POST   /users/:user_id/elements(.:format)          elements#create
user_elements DELETE /users/:user_id/elements/:CHANGED(.:format)       elements#destroy
```

Thanks!!

Comment: why do you need something other than id?

Comment: because I have an other field that is unique, but it's a string so I choose to have an int id and also this unique string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend against changing the convention.  You will probably need to declare the routes manually.

That said, something like this would probably work:

```
  resources :users do
     post 'elements(.:format)' => 'elements#create'
     delete  'elements/:changed(.:format)' => 'elements#destroy'
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
match "/users/:user_id/elements/:CHANGED(.:format)" => 'elements#destroy'
```

This can do it!